# Make image draggable and resizable within div

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable, resizable

Let me share what I actually want -

1. Create a div.
2. Onclick add an image to the div.
3. Make this image draggable and resizable.
4. We would be able to add multiple image into the div.

Below is my code I've done so far -

JS :

```
$.fn.extend({
      draggableChildren: function(selector) {
           $(this).on("mouseover", selector, function() {
                    if(!$(this).is(":ui-draggable"))
                          $(this).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
                    });
                    return this;
              }
        });

$.fn.extend({
      resizableChildren: function(selector) {
           $(this).on("mouseover", selector, function() {
                    if(!$(this).is(":ui-resizable"))
                          $(this).resizable({ containment: "parent" });
                    });
              }
        });

$(document).ready(function(){
      setImageProperty=function(imageSource){
            $(".block").draggableChildren(".blocks");
            $(".block").resizableChildren(".blocks");
            $(".block").append('<img class="blocks" src='+imageSource+' />');
    }});
```

CSS :

```
.blocks 
    {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    }

.block 
    {
    width:50%;
    height : 50%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #C8C8C8;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position : relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/upload_common.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/upload_common.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <br><div class="block"></div>
    <center>
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="showExistingImg" value="Show Uploaded Images" />
    <input id="style_Browse" type="button" value="Upload Images" class="button" />
    <input id="btn_browse" type="file" onchange="loadname(this,'previewImg');" />
    <div id="existingImges">

    <br>
    <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setImageProperty('../images/1.jpg')" ><img class="uploadImage" src="../images/1.jpg" /></a>
     <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setImageProperty('../images/2.jpg')" ><img class="uploadImage" src="../images/2.jpg" /></a>
     <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setImageProperty('../images/3.jpg')" ><img class="uploadImage" src="../images/3.jpg" /></a>
     </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Problem is I can make the image either draggable or resizable. Not both. For instance, in the code above, the image is resizable, not draggable. Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Please find the attached fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/249/

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi Thorsten, Fiddle created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I simplified your code a little bit. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/8VY52/250/

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.block-add', function () {
    var a = $(this);
    var src = a.find('img:first').attr('src');
    var elem = $('<div class="container"><img src="' + src + '" class="blocks" /></div>');
    $('.block').append(elem);
    elem.draggable();
    elem.find('.blocks:first').resizable();
    return false;
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<br/>
<div class="block"></div>
 <center>
    <br/>
    <div id="existingImges">
        <br/><a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage"  src="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png" /></a>
 <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage"    src="http://www.a1smallbusinessmarketing.com/images/prosbo_hires.jpg" /></a>
 <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png" /></a>
 <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png" /></a>
    </div>
 </center>
```

You should wrap image into a div and then bind draggable on the container and resizable on the image. It has something to do with how jQuery draggable and resizable works.

[jQuery Ticket for resizable and draggable on image](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4241)

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/8VY52/247/

```
$('#draggableHelper').draggable();
$('#image').resizable();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="draggableHelper">
    <img id="image" src="image-src" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kamlesh, Thanks for your efforts. Could you please have a look at the fiddle I have created. I really can't rely on id, because images are dynamically added and have same class not id.

Comment: Your second example works for me in jsfiddle, but when I paste it into my own local html page it does not work. The code is exactly the same with the addition of a link to jquery 2.2.2 of course. Also, when trying out your first example in jsfiddle there seems to be invisible draggable spots to the right of the images.

Comment: @kojow7 Did you find any errors in the console when running local html pages

Comment: Got it figured out, thanks! By looking at the console I realized that I needed to install jQuery UI.