# Best way to make png draggable ignoring transparent area

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

I have 'png' files with some irregular shapes. I need to make them draggable but only the non-transparent area should work as handler for mouse events. Please let me know what is the best way to implement the same.

I have already tried it using 'map' but draggable does not works with map.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405472/make-image-draggable-and-resizable-within-div

Comment: Please include the code you have problems with.

Comment: I very much doubt you have png images with "irregular shapes"...I'll lay odds they are rectangular. The non-transparent sections of the images might be irregular but you can't separate them from the image overall. Images don't have contents. Sounds like you might want SVG.

Comment: Is this png image an img-tag (i.e. a DOM element) or drawn (drawImage();) on the canvas? (I know the tags say canvas but just wanted to make sure since it also says CSS)

Answer (score 2):

If your png image is drawn on the canvas, you can check the pixel you have clicked.

Let's say you clicked (x,y)

```
var currentCanvas = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
var pix = currentCanvas.data;

if (pix[3] > 0) { //0 is transparent, 255 is fully visible
    //clicked a non-transparent area and thus it is draggable
}
```

This solution assumes that the background is also transparent so you can't have anything else drawn behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to start dragging an image only if the mouse starts dragging in a non-transparent part of the image:

- Use `context.getImageData` to get the pixel information about your image(s).
- Create an array that holds the alpha information about the image
- To start drag events, listen for mousedown events and check the alpha array to see if the mouse was pressed inside an image. If yes, start the drag.

**Here's annotated example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var hitArray
var draggables=[];

var testImg=new Image();
testImg.crossOrigin='anonymous';
testImg.onload=start;
testImg.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/pikachu.png";
function start(){

  draggables.push({
    img:testImg,
    x:50,
    y:50,
    width:testImg.width,
    height:testImg.height,
    hitarray:makeHitArray(testImg),
    isDragging:false,
  });

  draggables.push({
    img:testImg,
    x:150,
    y:50,
    width:testImg.width,
    height:testImg.height,
    hitarray:makeHitArray(testImg),
    isDragging:false,
  });

  // listen for mouse events
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

  drawAll();

}

function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<draggables.length;i++){
    var d=draggables[i];
    ctx.drawImage(d.img,d.x,d.y);
  }
}

// Draw a target image on a canvas
// Get the imageData of that canvas
// Make an array containing the opacity of each pixel on the canvas
// ( 0==pixel is not part of the object, 1==pixel is part of the object)
function makeHitArray(img){
  var a=[];
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
    // if this pixel is mostly opaque push 1 else push 0
    a.push(data[i+3]>250?1:0);
  }
  canvas.width=cw;
  canvas.height=ch;
  return(a);
}

function hitTest(mx,my,d){
  // return if the mouse is not inside the image bounds
  if(mx<d.x || mx>d.x+d.width || my<d.y || my>d.y+d.height){return;}
  // undo the effects of the image not being at [0,0]
  x=mx-d.x;
  y=my-d.y;
  // calculate which index in the hitarray to test
  index=(y*d.width)+x;
  // test the hitarray
  if(d.hitarray[index]>0){
    // the mouse is over an opaque part of the image
    return(true);
  }else{
    // the mouse is not over an opaque part of the image
    return(false);
  }
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the mouse position
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Set the dragging flags if the mouse was down over 
  // an opaque part of the draggable image
  isDown=false;
  for(var i=0;i<draggables.length;i++){
    var d=draggables[i];
    d.isDragging=hitTest(startX,startY,d);
    if(d.isDragging){
      isDown=true;
    }
  }         
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // calculate how far the mouse has moved since the last move event
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

  // iterate draggables and move any that are being dragged
  for(var i=0;i<draggables.length;i++){
    var d=draggables[i];
    if(d.isDragging){
      d.x+=dx;
      d.y+=dy;
    }
  }

  drawAll();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```